# TryValidateObject always returns true

Tags: .net, vb.net, validation, data-annotations

I have this piece of code:

```
Dim context = New System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(p, Nothing, Nothing)
Dim results = New List(Of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult)
Dim isValid = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.TryValidateObject(p, context, results)
```

p is the object that I try to validate. It has a property:

```
<Range(Double.Epsilon, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage:="Provide a positive amount value.")>
Public Property Amount As Decimal Implements ICrmOpportunityProductData.Amount
```

Although Amount is 0 when I am validating it (so invalid, because 0 is smaller than epsilon), isValid is true and there are no errors in results list. Why?

**EDIT**

To avoid problems with convertion I changed the range attribute to validate from 1:

```
<Range(1.0, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage:="Provide a positive amount value.")>
Public Property Amount As Decimal Implements ICrmOpportunityProductData.Amount
```

And still validation does not return any errors for Amount = 0.

Comment: Maybe the validator converts the values specified in the Range attribute to Decimal since the type of amount is Decimal?

Comment: I didn't realize that the types were different. The validation works though, when validated normally during POST. Only manual validation fails. I will have a look into it a bit more

Answer (score 0):

The msdn documentation seems pretty vague on how the objects actually get compared.
But one of the pages
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.operandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
States that the object must implement IComparable

Most liekly obj.CompareTo is called and AFAIK the (not a static method)Decimal.CompareTo method throws and ArgumentException if passed anything that's not a Decimal

Double.Epsilon converted to Decimal is 0

Comment: Thanks for the input. Decimal implements IComparable. I changed Double.Epsilon to 1, but it is still the same...